# SQL RegEx to handle comma separated IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a string that denotes which users are allowed to access something. For instance, if user 1, user 2, and user 3 could access it, the `accessibility` column would contain `1,2,3`. If only user 1 could access it, it would only be `1` and so forth.

I know I can't do a simple `CONTAINS` clause because searching for `1` could return true for `14,2,3`. How would I get a regex to accommodate when there is a comma on both sides, on one side, or neither of the ID number?

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do

```
DataID: 1
Accessibility: "1,2,3,4,5"
Data: "secret stuff"

DataID: 2
Accessibility: "5,6,7,8,9"
Data: "more secret stuff"
```

I need to tell the regex to search for a number and to make sure its at the beginning of the string and the end of the string if it has no commas around it, is at the beginning of the string if it only has a comma after it, is at the end of a string if it only has a comma before it, or if it commas on both sides that's fine because it's in the middle of the string.

I know what I need to do, but don't know how to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have a really bad data structure for several reasons:

- The proper way to store lists in SQL is using tables, not strings.
- The proper way to store integers in SQL is as integers, not strings.
- Ids should be defined with a proper foreign key relationship, which you cannot do when the id is stored in a string.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  That is, we are unable to create a proper junction table, with one column for the `DataId` and *each* user who has access to it.

In that situation, you can use the `find_in_set()` functionality in MySQL.  This does not require a regular expression.  You can just write:

```
where find_in_set($user, accessibility) > 0
```

Comment: Yes it is a matter of manipulating retrieved data written by someone else. I thought about making a cron-job to parse it all and store it properly but if it is a simple work-around, I would prefer to just access it on the fly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since A-Z, 0-9, and underscore are considered word boundaries, you could generalize like this:

-- word-bound DataID, e.g. 1 becomes \b1\b
SELECT '\b' || DataID || '\b' AS DataID_Bound FROM USER
WHERE REGEX_LIKE(DataID_Bound, Accessibility)

That way it doesn't matter if there is a comma leading, trailing, or if it's a sole occupant of the search subject.  But it deffinitely cannot match 14 or 21, etc.  \b1\b will only match solo 1, \b14\b will only match whole word 14, etc.